# ListView class cast error using ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using a ViewHolder in order to display different background for each row of my listview. Basically the image from the background comes from a server and loads into an `ImageView`. I then set my `RelativeLayout` background to be that `ImageView`. However, in implementing the viewHolder in order to achieve this i get a class cast exception at the line :

`viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.setTag();`

Here is my full implementation:

**MyArrayAdapter.java**

```
@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.imageBackground = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageBKG);
        viewHolder.rowlist = (RelativeLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_mallx);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
   else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

   Mall mall = malls.get(position);

   viewHolder.rowlist.setBackground(viewHolder.imageBackground.getDrawable());
   ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mall.iconWide, viewHolder.imageBackground, Utility.displayImageOptions);

   return rowView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageBackground;
    public RelativeLayout rowlist;
}
```

**row_list.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/row_mallx"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="155dp">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageBKG"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.adapter.MyArrayAdapter$ViewHolder
        at com.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.adapter.MyArrayAdapter.getView(MyArrayAdapter.java:68)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2413)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:636)
```

Comment: @kalyanpvs posted. Please have a look

Comment: you are passing R.layout.row_list as resourceId  in inflater right?

Comment: your posted code seems to be ok..there is some other mistake post your total adapter code

Comment: @stud91: what is line number `68` in `MyArrayAdapter.java` ?

Comment: can u pls post whole adapter code and Mall Class too ? as error seem to be casting from adapter and string related..

Comment: Are you setting a Tag to your `rowView` other than this line `rowView.setTag(viewHolder);` ??

Comment: post your values for viewHolder.imageBackground.getDrawable() and mall.iconWide

Comment: why are you doing View rowView = convertView; is it not redundant

Comment: @stud91 : as in log `.String cannot be cast to ViewHolder` clearly mean trying to cast `String` to ViewHolder class. post whole code of `getView` method

Comment: i think you are use ArrayAdapter<String>  for extend your adapter class?

Comment: @stud91Did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the inflater that you are using.

Here is the correct way of initialising the `Inflater`and i suggest that you initialise it in your Adapter's constructor, rather than re-initialising it every time when `getView(..)` is being called.

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Along with that you should also inflate your rowView like this:

```
rowView = inflater.inflate( resourceId, null );
```

instead of initialising it like this:

```
 rowView = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
```

Well to be more specific, the error is occurring in this Line :

```
else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
}
```

When you are trying to extract 'ViewHolder' Object from the rowView's Tag and instead getting some sort of String.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This what your were missing

***holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();***

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.child_row, arg2, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageBackground = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageBKG);
        viewHolder.rowlist = (RelativeLayout) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.row_mallx);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // rowView = convertView;
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }
    holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();//This is your ultimate problem 
    viewHolder.rowlist.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    holder.imageBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.imageBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    return rowView;
}
```

hope this will help :) 
Happy coding.

Comment: Why are you calling `getTag()` twice?